# How do I configure my htaccess file to have a wildcard catch for unrecognized subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, hosting, wildcard, query-string

I currently have an .htaccess file that has been configured like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.me$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.me$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.me\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Using this method I have my unknown subdomains routing to the built in ***/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi*** but I would like it to reroute to a custom error page that I have made. For instance, if a user were to enter "***notarealaddress.domain.me***" it should then route them to a 404 page like "***domain.me/404?page=notarealaddress***". It is important to me that I maintain the query string in the 404 url because I have the 404 page dynamically change based on what they tried to reach. It is worth noting that it must still handle known subdomains, for instance if they user enters "***arealaddress.domain.me***" it should take them to the appropriate page still instead of the 404 page.

I'm fairly new to the web hosting management side of web development so I am at a loss of what to do at this point. I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Well, you need a rule with the additional condition that the host name is NOT "domain.me" AND NOT "www.domain.me".

Comment: And by the way, your current rule set looks like a rewriting loop to me...